# How to rasterize simple geometry from GeoJSON file using GDAL?

Tags: python-2.7, gdal

I am trying to rasterize simple Point & Line geometry using Python GDAL and I am not able perform it. e.g. I have 3 points as follows in Lat-Lon format in the json file.

[ 2.19326073965, 49.049766213940003 ], [ 2.19289443625, 49.049622431300001 ], [ 2.19271641965, 49.049547116589999 ]

What are the steps to create a tif file after rasterizing this GeoJSON file? I found various articles but could not understand and tried the following code but generated tif file is black.

```
pixel_size = 1.0
NoData_value = 100
# Filename of input OGR file
vector_fn = 'point_out.geojson'

# Filename of the raster Tiff that will be created
raster_fn = 'test.tif'

# Open the data source and read in the extent
source_ds = ogr.Open(vector_fn)
source_layer = source_ds.GetLayer()
x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max = source_layer.GetExtent()

print x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max
# Create the destination data source
x_res = int((x_max - x_min) / pixel_size)
y_res = int((y_max - y_min) / pixel_size)
print x_res, y_res
target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(raster_fn, 1300, 1300, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
target_ds.SetGeoTransform([1, pixel_size, 0, 1, 0, -pixel_size])
band = target_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
band.SetNoDataValue(NoData_value)

# Rasterize
gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], source_layer, burn_values=[128])
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define the raster geotransform in the same coordinates as the vector data, not in pixel coordinates.

If for those three vertices in a line-string, you define the raster like for example:

```
target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(raster_fn, 100, 100, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
target_ds.SetGeoTransform([2.1925, 0.00001, 0, 49.05, 0, -0.00001])
```

The result will look like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rutger. got it.